# Three Images With Text Underneath, But The Text Repositions Beside The Images On Smaller Screens

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I know posting of images is discouraged, but I really think this greatly helps explain what I'm going for.

I have three images which I would like positioned next to each other (blue squares), with text beneath each (red squares) on larger screens. On smaller screens I'd like the text to position next to the images, and for the image/text pairs to stack vertically.

I'm guessing this would best be done with Bootstrap. I know how to use Bootstrap Grid so that the images stack vertically on smaller screens, but I dont know how to get this combined effect.

Here is my code so far with the images that are next to each other on larger screens but stack vertically on smaller screens.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

         <div class="col-md d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md- 
         start">
             <img src="{% static 'home/img.png' %}" />
         </div>

         <div class="col-md d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md- 
         start">
             <img src="{% static 'home/img.png' %}" />
         </div>

         <div class="col-md d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md- 
         start">
             <img src="{% static 'home/img.png' %}" />
         </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

[image: Three Images With Text Underneath, But The Text Repositions Beside The Images On Smaller Screens]

Comment: Use `<figcaption>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `flex-md-column` in order to achieve this with bootstrap.

If the screensize is higher than the md breakpoint, the text will go under the image instead of next to it. The default setting for flexbox is row so under the breakpoint it just uses the default setting, above the breakpoint it converts it to the column setting.

```
<div class="col-md d-flex flex-md-column justify-content-center">
    <img src="{% static 'home/img.png' %}" />
</div>
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#direction